# openvpn communication during renegotiation

Tags: openvpn

I'm using openvpn setup where I implement custom authentication on the server with a `auth-user-pass-verify` script. This script accesses a remote server so the process usually takes 10-40 seconds. Additionally I have `reneg-sec` configured to renegotiate every 30 minutes.

The problem is that every time the renegotiation starts, the client connection is not working until the reneg ends. It makes a lot of sense to have the connection up until some configurable timeout on the reneg. I tried looking at `hand-window` or `tran-window` configs which seemed related but nothing helped.

Is there a way to maintain the connection during openvpn renegotiation process?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `auth-gen-token 0` option. According to the doc

> the OpenVPN server will with this option generate a temporary authentication
> token  and  push  that  to client.  On the following renegotiations, the
> OpenVPN client will pass this token instead of the users
> password.  On the server side the server will do the token authentication
> internally and it will NOT do any additional  authentications against
> configured external user/password authentication mechanisms.

So this way the renegotiation will occur, but it will not call the long auth process, so it will not stall the connection.

Comment: Thanks for this info, didn't know about that option. Unfortunately I do want to verify on the remote server that the user is still authorized. So using this token is the same for me as not using reneg at all.